# How do you make SFTP Upload operation from single threaded to multithreaded?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-integration, sftp, spring-integration-sftp

I'm kind of new to the Multithreading approach. currently, in my code I am using ExecutorService Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor() to span a single thread that checks for files in a particular Directory if present I will fetch n files path(ex: n=5 files path) and will perform SFTP Operations of 5 files one by one.
But when I have a Large number of files the single-threaded approach will take a lot of time to sftp each file one by one.

SftpUpload Service class:-

```
 @Autowired
 private  UploadMessageGateway gateway;

 public void uploadFile(File file) throws SftpException
  {
    try
     {
        gateway.uploadFile(file);
     }
    catch (Exception e)
     {
        logger.error(" Exception found at SftpUpload {} ",
                e.getMessage());
     } 
   }
```

sftp gateway:-

```
@MessagingGateway
public interface UploadMessageGateway
{
    @Gateway(requestChannel = "uploadfile")
    void uploadFile(File file);
}
```

sftp config file:-

```
@Bean
public SessionFactory<ChannelSftp.LsEntry>  factoryDetails() throws 
SftpException {
    DefaultSftpSessionFactory factory = new DefaultSftpSessionFactory();
    factory.setHost(host);
    factory.setPort(port);
    factory.setAllowUnknownKeys(true);
    factory.setUser(username);
    factory.setPassword(password);
    CachingSessionFactory<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> cachingSessionFactory = new CachingSessionFactory<>(factory);
    cachingSessionFactory.setTestSession(true);

    return new CachingSessionFactory<ChannelSftp.LsEntry>(factory);
}

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "uploadfile")
public MessageHandler uploadHandler()
{
    SessionFactory<ChannelSftp.LsEntry>
            defaultSessionFactory= factoryDetails();
    sftpMessageHandler = new SftpMessageHandler(defaultSessionFactory);
    sftpMessageHandler.setRemoteDirectoryExpression(
            new LiteralExpression(remotePath,
                    defaultSessionFactory)));
    return sftpMessageHandler;
 }
```

is it a better option to use the spring-batch master-slave approach or to make use of Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5) or is there any standard approach? your suggestions/links will be very helpful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like better to use an SFTP Inbound Channel Adapter instead of something manual: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/sftp.html#sftp-inbound.

You can have then an `ExecutorChannel` to process those emitted messages in parallel.

You might not need that `UploadMessageGateway` though since everything is going to be build as an integration flow from beginning to the end.